# Scala implicit class

Tags: mongodb, scala, implicit

I am seeing some unexpected behavior with an implicit class. I have a case class that is retrieved from Mongo, and in certain cases wrapped into an implicit class with convenience lazy vals to retrieve data from other relevant collections. Code looks something like

```
case class MyClass(
    _id: UUID, ...,
    //some fields
)
```

and then

```
object MyImplicits {

    implicit class MyRichClass(c: MyClass){
        lazy val field1: Future[Iterable[T1]] = db.findAll[T1](bson)
        lazy val field2: Future[Iterable[T2]] = db.findAll[T2](bson)
    }

}
```

and the conversion is used like

```
import ...MyImplicits.MyRichClass
val c: MyClass...
c.field1.map(...)
```

My problem is Futures in field1 and field2 always contain an empty Iterable. I have spent best part of today debugging my queries, and they work correctly both in test code and Mongo cli.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

I have a wrapper around org.mongodb.scala.MongoClient, that has:

```
/**
* Finds all instances of T using raw mongo query
*
* @param bson search query
* @tparam T
* @return
*/
private[service] def findAll[T: ClassTag](bson: Bson): Future[Iterable[T]] = {
    val colName = resolveCollection[T]
    logger.info("colName = " + colName)
    db.getCollection[T](colName).find(equal("ownerId", "user1")).toFuture().map(t => {
      logger.info("t = " + t)
      t
    })
}


/**
* Returns collection name for given type
* @tparam T
* @return
*/
private def resolveCollection[T: ClassTag]: String = {
scala.reflect.classTag[T] match {
  case `...tag` => "collectionName"
  ....
}
```

}

The

```
 equal("ownerId", "user1")
```

is hardcoded for debugging purposes, as well as extra loggers.

Comment: Just to make sure, your `MyClass` doesn't have a field `field1`, right?

Comment: no, it does not.

Comment: The devil is in the details and you are missing all the important ones. You will need to share a minimal implementation with full details on some sample class. How exactly are you doing that "some mongo query" is the most important.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh I have updated the question

Comment: The devil is indeed in the details.... I was running my code in a spec, while I set up data in another dev db. Ugh... Problem is between the chair and keyboard.

Comment: Using `lazy val` as fields to load data lazily from a database sounds like a source for a whole lot of trouble to me. It's hiding a lot of detail in something that is trivial as a class field.

Comment: Have checked this future itself - `val field1: Future[Iterable[T1]] = db.findAll[T1](bson)` ?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov while I do not disagree, I chose this approach because it directly mirrors document relationships and avoids querying many collections unnecessarily, as well as driver Im using is able to (de)serialize simple case classes with no other fields besides ones in constructor and I did not want to spend time writing custom logic for it.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually no issues with the code. I was literally querying a wrong database, so, yes - all collections were in fact empty.